# How do you disable Facebook notifications in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, facebook

I'm not sure how they got turned on... but now whenever I open Chrome, whether on Facebook or not, I constantly receive Facebook popup notifications.

How do I turn this feature off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `chrome://settings/contentExceptions#notifications`, or navigate as follows:

`Menu` -> `Settings`

From here, open `Show Advanced Settings` -> `Privacy` -> `Content Settings`

Under here is a section titled `Notifications`. Either click `Do not allow any site to show notifications` or remove the exception for Facebook under `Manage Exceptions`

[image]